Can doxygen link to a namespace within a folder that includes periods in the folder name?
Given a folder like com.org.Project that contains a file myClass.py is it possible to provide a link in a Markdown file to the myClass namespace?
When I provide the string com.org.Project.myClass the link goes here docs/html/d4/d5d/namespacecom_1_1org_1_1_Project_1_1myClass.html instead of docs/html/d4/db0/namespacecom_8org_8_Project_1_1myClass.html.
The result I see is that only a portion of the myClass namespace is described (the header comment within """...""") but not the methods or other elements of that same file.

Found I can use \ref com.org.Project/myClass.py to link to the file.  It is enough.  I am still wondering though if it is possible to link to the namespace?
